# How to SELECT date and time within that date?

Tags: mysql

I read few articles about this: [Select max date, then max time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255305/select-max-date-then-max-time) This one seems most helpful but I do not see way to implement it.

There is five tables. I join them. I need to select only one row with highest date and highest time from first table and same from second table and join the rest on some other value. With the code I wrote I get multiple rows. It seems time selection is not right.

It might be done with subquery in subquery. I've tried something like this:

```
    SELECT * from table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.date = table2.date AND table1.gm = table2.gm        
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.gm = table3.gm        ...
    WHERE table3.date = :date AND table4.date = :date ...
    AND table1.date IN(
        SELECT MAX(table1.date) FROM table1 WHERE table1.time IN(
            SELECT MAX(table1.time) FROM table1
    )
    )
    AND table2.date IN(
        SELECT MAX(table2.date) FROM table1 WHERE table2.time IN(
            SELECT MAX(table2.time) FROM table2        )
    )
    ORDER BY table1.id
```

Question is:
How to get single row after joining all of this where date is highest and time is highest on that date?
Thanks!

EDIT: I am sorry for this. I forgot to say that I need max time of max date related with specific value from tables(gm columns). So that is one row(in example I gave it is table1.gm and table2.gm ... ) for each one of that .gm values which are same in every table, not just one row all together. Solutions Nick and Salim provided works but I did not solved problem.

EDIT: SOLVED! after implementing solutions by Nick I just neded to add GROUP BY cntrs_reper.gm_company_no, cntrs_reper.date.
And that's it. For every row in one table enties with highest date and time from others!! Thanks to all.

EDIT. If this can help this is full query:

```
SELECT  cntrs_gm.gm_company_no                          AS      company_c_g,  
 bns_gms.ded_bns                                    AS      ded_bns_gms,  
     bns_gms.no_ded_bns                             AS      no_ded_bns_gms,  
     bns_gms.wag_ded_bns                            AS      wag_ded_bns_gms,  
     cntrs_gm.cur_credit                            AS      cur_credit_c_g,  
     cntrs_gm.cdrop                                 AS      cdrop_c_g,  
     cntrs_gm.total_jp                              AS      total_jp_c_g,  
     cntrs_gm.games                                 AS      games_c_g,  
     cntrs_gm.wgames                                AS      wgames_c_g,  
     cntrs_gm.doors                                 AS      doors_c_g,  
     cntrs_gm.power                                 AS      power_c_g,  
     cntrs_gm.total_in                            AS        total_in_c_g,  
     cntrs_gm.total_out                           AS        total_out_c_g,  
     cntrs_gm.total_acc                           AS        total_acc_c_g,  
     cntrs_gm.total_bet                           AS        total_bet_c_g,  
     cntrs_gm.total_win                           AS        total_win_c_g,  
     cntrs_gm.total_bonus                         AS        total_bonus_c_g,  
     cntrs_gm.date              AS      date_c_g,  
     cntrs_reper.gm_company_no                    AS        company_reper,  
 bns_reper.ded_bns                            AS        ded_bns_reper,  
     bns_reper.no_ded_bns                         AS        no_ded_bns_reper,  
     bns_reper.wag_ded_bns          AS      wag_ded_bns_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.cur_credit         AS      cur_credit_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.cdrop              AS      cdrop_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.total_jp                         AS        total_jp_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.games              AS      games_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.wgames             AS      wgames_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.doors              AS      doors_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.power              AS      power_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.total_in                         AS        total_in_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.total_out          AS      total_out_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.total_acc          AS      total_acc_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.total_bet          AS      total_bet_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.total_win          AS      total_win_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.total_bonus            AS      total_bonus_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.date                             AS        date_reper,  
     cntrs_reper.time               AS      time_reper,
     bns_reper.time                 AS      time_c_g,
     gms_cfg.gm_no                                    AS              machine_id,  
     gms_cfg.denom_cin                        AS              machine_cin  
     FROM bns_gms  
     INNER JOIN cntrs_gm  
     ON bns_gms.gm_company_no = cntrs_gm.gm_company_no  AND bns_gms.date = cntrs_gm.date
     INNER JOIN bns_reper 
     ON cntrs_gm.gm_company_no = bns_reper.gm_company_no  
     INNER JOIN cntrs_reper  
     ON bns_reper.gm_company_no = cntrs_reper.gm_company_no  AND bns_reper.date = cntrs_reper.date
     INNER JOIN gms_cfg  
     ON cntrs_reper.gm_company_no =  gms_cfg.gm_no  
     WHERE   bns_reper.date IN(
        SELECT MAX(DATE(bns_reper.date)) FROM bns_reper WHERE bns_reper.time IN(
            SELECT MAX(TIME(bns_reper.time)) FROM bns_reper
        )
        )
     AND cntrs_reper.date IN(
        SELECT MAX(DATE(cntrs_reper.date)) FROM cntrs_reper  WHERE cntrs_reper.time IN(
            SELECT MAX(TIME(cntrs_reper.time)) FROM cntrs_reper
        )
        )

     ORDER BY cntrs_gm.gm_company_no
```

DB example

[bns_gms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aPXE.jpg)

[bns_reper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCMKQ.jpg)

[cntrs_gm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMkC6.jpg)

[cntrs_reper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPr5c.jpg)

[gms_cfg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5YHB.jpg)

Comment: Try using `MAX(DATE(table1.date))` and `MAX(TIME(table2.date))`. First one will return MAX date, second - MAX time.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it returns multiple rows again.

Comment: What do you mean by `join the rest on some other value`? Join other tables in the same query? What are the relations between table1, table2 where you find MAX date and MAX time and other 3 tables?

Comment: Other 3 tables do not have time column. They always have just on entry per day that updates all the time. I join them on date and on some id number. Yes I join them in the same query. I will edit with question with full query if needed?

Comment: Can you provide examples of the data you have in your tables? It will be helpful to test joins or compare results.

Comment: There is data example. Question edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current query is that it will select all rows where table1.date is the latest date on which the highest time occurs, which may well be more than one e.g. for data such as

```
id  date          time
1   2018-03-30    18:40
2   2018-03-31    12:20
3   2018-03-31    19:20
```

Your `WHERE` clause:

```
table1.date IN(
    SELECT MAX(table1.date) FROM table1 WHERE table1.time IN(
        SELECT MAX(table1.time) FROM table1
)
```

will select rows with `id=2` and `id=3` as they both have `date = '2018-03-31'` which is when the maximum time occurs.

What you want to do is select the row which has the latest time on the latest date, for which you could use

```
table1.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table1) AND
table1.time = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM table1 WHERE date = (SELECT(MAX(date) FROM table1))
```

By using aliasing, that can be simplified (since we already know `table1.date = MAX(date) FROM table1`) to

```
table1.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table1) AND
table1.time = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM table1 AS t1 WHERE t1.date = table1.date)
```

Comment: Nick thank you! I tried to implement what you suggested. It works just as you said. Thing is I forgot to say very important thing. It should return one row per certain column value. All tables are related with samo value. It is gms_cfg_gm and *.gm_company_no in all other. There is 39 rows. I should get max time and max date by each of them. So result should contain 39 rows. If you have any suggestion further I am ready to listen.

Comment: Hi Pera, looks like you sorted out that issue for yourself?

Comment: With a big help of yours! I couldn't find that  (SELECT MAX(time) FROM table1 AS t1 WHERE t1.date = table1.date) solution. That's why your answer is accepted.

Comment: Thanks - I'm glad I was able to help you solve the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MySQL but here is the general idea you can use. I don't have enough points to write a comment so I am responding as a reply. Essentially make a subquery/inline view for each table to select max of a column, then join those subqueries/inline views together.

Here is Oracle syntax. You can convert it to ANSI syntax.

```
select table1.column1, table2.column2,table3.column3 
from
(select id1, max(column1) as column1 from table1 group by id1) as table1
(select id2, max(column2) as column2 from table2  group by id2) as table2
(select id3, max(column3) as column3 from table3  group by id3) as table3
where 
table1.id1 = table2.id2
and table1.id1 = table3.id3
;
```

Comment: Thanks Salim. I implemented Nick's solution. But your answer gave me idea on the other part to use group by. I can not vote yet but as soon as I can I will give you +1!